# Creating a Sliding Menu

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-menu, slidingmenu

I need to create a sliding menu. The case is, this is not like the day to day sliding menus we find, this is bit different.

[image]

As in the above image, the menu "opener" should be at the bottom of the screen. This is always visible. You can see this "menu opener" in grey colour.

When the user touches on this grey colour bar and slides up, it should open themenu like following.

[image]

I visited [SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) project and this does not contains what I am seeking for, because, the menu is invisible until you slide. But in my case, the "menu opener(grey colour bar") is always visible.

How can I do something like this?

Comment: PLease follow the android guidelines regarding design as much as possible. These actions should be located in ActionBar or in the overflow menu of the ActionBar

Comment: i dont know how to do this, but this feature is present in the latest update of google plus, when you click on an image you get share buttons on your 'grey area' at bottom and on clicking it you can slide up to get apps where you can share

Comment: @user1281750: This is a client requirement, not my design. Anyway, can you please give me the link?

Comment: ok, if you don't have a choice a will try to give you a way of working that could help. First add your custom view to android.R.id.content (framelayout) with a gravity set to bottom. Then when view gets clicked animate the opening of view.

Comment: Isnt it similar to [SlidingDrawer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html)?! same concept and you can resize the drawer

Comment: @OsamaEspil: Hi, This is the answer. Great! Submit it as an answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check SlidingDrawer [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html). you can adjust the drawer as you desire as well.